# search string for values in specific format

Tags: c#, string, format

How can you extract values from a string like this: Lambertseter_InfoCloseDay_07_09_2014_19_55_52 ?

The format is like this: `<Location>_<TypeOfFile>_<DD>_<MM>_<YYYY>_<HH>_<MM>_<SS>`

I tried this:

```
        string Mystring = "Lambertseter_InfoCloseDay_07_09_2014_19_55_52";
        string[] splittedFileString = Mystring.Split('_');
        string[] formatArray = { "Bingohall: ", "Filetype: ", "Day: ", "Month: ", "Year: ", "Hour: ", "Minute: ", "Second: " };

        for (int i = 0; i < formatArray.Length; i++)
        {
            formatArray[i] += splittedFileString[i];
        }
```

This seems to work at least, but am I doing this the right way? Is there a simpler method for managing strings this way?

Comment: What you're doing seems fine to me unless you're expecting that string format to change at which point a dynamic regex solution might be best. Otherwise, string.split keeps it simple. If it ain't broken, there's no need to fix it!

Answer (score 0):

If your data is this regular, this regular expression would work:

```
var regex = new Regex(@"(?<Location>\w+)_(?<TypeOfFile>\w+)_(?<DD>\d+)_(?<MM>\d+)_(?<YYYY>\d+)_(?<HH>\d+)_(?<MIN>\d+)_(?<SS>\d+)", RegexOptions.ExplicitCapture);
var match = regex.Match("Lambertseter_InfoCloseDay_07_09_2014_19_55_52");
var groups = match.Groups;
var output = $"Bingohall: {groups["Location"].Value}, Filetype: {groups["TypeOfFile"].Value}, Day: {groups["DD"].Value}, Month: {groups["MM"].Value}, Year: {groups["YYYY"].Value}, Hour: {groups["HH"].Value}, Minute: {groups["MIN"].Value}, Second: {groups["SS"].Value}";
```